# Does a Typed Memoryview Increase A numpy.array's Reference Count?

Tags: numpy, cython, memoryview

Some code of the type shown below, caused me memory corruptions in C++ code called through Cython. I've managed to solve it, but would like to ask what is the *minimum* required to solve it.

Suppose:

- `CFoo` is a C++ class with some member `set_ptr` taking a pointer to a double. The Cython class `Foo` Holds a pointer to a `CFoo`.
- Within some `bar` method of `Foo`:

  - A transient `numpy.array`, `a`, is created by calling `function_returning_a_numpy_array()`.
  - A typed memoryview, `a_view` is created for viewing `a`.
  - A pointer from `a_view` is sent to `CFoo` using `CFoo`'s member `set_ptr`.

Snippet:

```
cdef class Foo:
    cdef CFoo *foo_imp;

    ...

    def bar(self):
        a = function_returning_a_numpy_array()
        cdef double a_view[:] = a
        foo_imp.set_ptr(&a_view[0])
```

Note that, in the context of this question, subsequent calls to `Foo` will cause `CFoo` to operate on this pointer.

It's pretty clear that as nothing is holding `a`, subsequent calls to `Foo`'s members can find the memory of `a` reclaimed. I've solved this by making `a` a member of `Foo`. My questions are:

- Would this be solved by making a `double *` (set to `&a_view[0]`) a member of `Foo`? I'm guessing that no.
- Would this be solved by making a `double a_view[:]` (set to `a`) a member of `Foo`? I can't find anything in the docs addressing this one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the `double*` a member of `Foo` wouldn't help (as you guess) because the refcount of `a` isn't incremented.

Making the `double a_view[:]` a member would help (although it isn't explicitly clear from the docs). The best hint I can see is http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#memoryview-objects-and-cython-arrays where the code example shows that you can retrieve the original object from the `base` attribute of the memory view.

A further illustration can be given using `sys.getrefcount`

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import numpy as np

def f():
    a = np.zeros((5,))
    print(sys.getrefcount(a))
    cdef double[:] b = a
    print(sys.getrefcount(a))
```

Running this prints 1 for the first line and 3 for the second. So it appears that the memory view actually stores two references to the numpy array (I don't know why)

Comment: This is a good answer - Thanks. I'm a bit apprehensive about deducing that it's definitive from stuff like the refcount, since it's an implementation that could possibly change (for this reason, I didn't look at the Cython-generated C++ code). Nevertheless, it's a clever test.